# Structure return and comparison with another function inside main

Tags: c, return, structure, call

Can you please help me understand something regarding structures?

I have created two structures with elements, here I have one in every case. I have a function called "function" that calculates the elements of the first structure struct_a and returns struct_a.

When I compile the code below, I receive two warnings:
warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast
warning: function returns address of local variable

What do I do wrong?

Now I want to call this structure inside main and put the elements of this to another structure.

First, is it correct the way I call it within the main? Or I should give some arguments?

The goal is that: Inside main, I want to put the values of the "struct_a" to the structure "car_a". Any advice please?

```
struct characteristics
{
    int element ; 

};

struct car type = {int alpha};

int function(){
    struct characteristics struct_a[10];
    sruct_a[2].element_a = var;

    return struct_a;
}

int main(){

    function();
    struct characteristics struct_a[10];

    car.alpha = struct_a[2].element_a;

}
```

Comment: If the function is supposed to return a struct, why define it to return an int? Also, var is not defined, please provide full code.

Comment: This `car.alpha = struct_a[2].element_a;` is wrong, you didn't initialize `struct_a` yet. Apparently you have no idea what scope is, but I'm guessing.

Comment: first of all typedef your structs - things read better

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Yes you are right, I changed it, can you check please? struct characteristics
{
    int element ; 
 int element1;
 int element2;

 
} ;

 
struct characteristics struct_a[10] ; 



struct characteristics function(struct characteristics x[10]){ 
 int var =25;
 int var1 = 35;
 int i=0;
    struct characteristics struct_a[10]= x[10] ;  
 
 
 
    return struct_a;
 
}

But I get : error: invalid initializer 
Why is the initializer wrong

Comment: I post here because the forum  it doesn't allow me to post an answer :
I did it in another way, do you agree? I define the two structures:

characteristics { 
int element; 
int element1; 
int element2; 
char element3[10]; 
};

struct car type = {
int alpha
int beta
int gamma
char name

};

continue below:

Comment: Then I write the function I use that I call later:

void function(struct characteristics struct_a[10]){

bla bla calculate struct_a;
}

Then I have the main where I define "choice" and "struct_a".

int main(){
    struct car_type choice;
 struct characteristics struct_a[10] ;

    function(struct_a);
    struct characteristics struct_a[10];

    car.alpha = struct_a[2].element1;

}

So normally if I print car_alpha I should have a value. But I guess zero. What do i miss? Thank you in advance people.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting warnings because you're defining `struct_a` to be an array of `characteristics` structures, meaning `struct_a` is the pointer (address) to the first structure in that array, while the function `function()` is expecting to return an `int` value.

You need to match the return type of `function()` with the variable type you are returning.

There are some other issues w/ the code, and I'm not entirely sure why `struct_a` is defined as an array in the first place, but maybe this will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you @shoul25. In the first structure I have more elements. Normally it is defined as : 

struct characteristics
{
 
 int element;
 
 int element1;
 
 int element2;
 
 char element3[10];
}; 

and indeed there is a char array here. Is there a way that I retrieve this structure in the main? How I should match the return type of the function() with the returning variable?